# Category templates in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

On my site, there will be two types of posts: `blog` and `portfolio`. I want to have a page for each of these categories, displaying only posts from that category.

What is the best way to achieve this in Jekyll? I've done some homework but I'm struggling to find a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put the post into folder `posts` and `portfolio`, jekyll will naturally defined two categories

```
root
 |-- posts
 |     `-- _posts
 |          |-- 2012-01-12-post.textile
 |          `-- 2012-03-22-post.textile
 `-- portfolio
      `-- _posts
            |-- 2011-04-05-post.textile
            `-- 2012-02-02-post.textile
```

Then you can have a generator that will create the category page, you may then take inspiration from this post: http://www.justkez.com/generating-a-tag-cloud-in-jekyll/ except that instead of generating the tag page, you generate the category page.

**EDIT**

There is also this plugins `generate_category.rb` that can help you: http://recursive-design.com/projects/jekyll-plugins/